# Adding edittext into a custom view

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view that looks a little like a speedometer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:slider="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.mysite.view.SeekBar_Speedometer
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    slider:fill_clockwise_color="@color/lightgrey"
    slider:fill_anticlockwise_color="@color/blue"
    slider:fill_handle_color="@color/green"
    slider:fill_handle_width="3"
    slider:angle_start="120"
    slider:angle_end="60"
    slider:fill_start_angle="120"
    slider:score_min="0"
    slider:score_max="300"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to add an edittext to the center of the speedometer.

Just as you can draw text to the canvas can I add an edittext in the same way from inside my view? I don't think so!

Question is, how do I go about adding this edittext to my custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your custom view class you can do:

```
EditText edit = new EditText(context);
addView( edit );
```

To do this your custom view must extends a ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ecc..)

Comment: Basically, nothing. It depends on what you're doing with your view. Just change your class extending LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: Ahhh! The speedometer just disapears. Looks like onDraw might work differently?

Comment: Maybe I could create a custom linearlayout and add my custom view and edittext to that?